# Internet Explorer 11 Flash of Unstyled Text (FOUT) when serving webfont

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, webfonts

I'm currently wondering if there is anything I can do about this. We're hosting a site on a cloud server that doesn't seem to have the fastest connection. This website is using a web font being served up with the following CSS/HTML:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('Montserrat-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Montserrat-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('Montserrat-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Montserrat-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

And link to it like so:

```
<link href="/montserrat-webfont/stylesheet.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      type="text/css" 
      media="all">
```

Pretty basic. Works great in every browser, even on the slow server, except for Internet Explorer 11. IE11 always flashes the fallback sans-serif font before displaying the Montserrat web font.

When I host the same site locally, I do not see the flash, I'm assuming because the page itself is loading much faster.

Is there anything I can do here? I made the font-family declaration `!important`, I made the `<link>` the very first thing in my `<head>`, and I still haven't been able to get rid of that flash of unstyled text on every single page load. Even when I go back to a page that should have been cached. It happens on every page load.

Comment: This could help: https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader -- One solution is to style your fallback fonts similar to your web fonts so when the FOUT occurs it won't be as noticeable